# how to set textbox value which is in modal to td

Tags: jquery, html, struts2

When I click edit button modal will pop up and display textbox with value  which is present in td of reference id my problem is when I change reference id and click update than the previous id must change with updated ref id
 ex: if I click row one edit button then only row 1 id as to change and not row 2.
  i need like this http://formvalidation.io/examples/loading-saving-data-modal/

```
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Month</label>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">

<s:select headerKey="" headerValue="--Select--"
                                                    list="#{'1':'JAN', '2':'FEB', '3':'MAR','4':'APR','5':'MAY','6':'JUN','7':'JUL', '8':'AUG', '9':'SEP', '10':'OCT','11':'NOV', '12':'Dec'}"
                                                        name="selctmonth" cssClass="form-control" />
                                                </div>
                                                <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Year</label>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <div class="input-group input-append date" id="yearPicker">
                                                        <s:textfield name="selctyear" cssClass="form-control"
                                                            id="yearofExam" />
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span
                                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                                    </div>




                                                </div>


                                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                                    <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>
                                    </s:form>
                                    <div id="row_dim">
                                        <
                                        <s:form id="downloadStudentMarksForm"
                                            action="downloadStudentMarks" theme="css_xhtml"
                                            cssClass="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">

                                            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                                                <table class="table table-bordered display nowrap"
                                                    id="dataTS">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;"></th>
                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Reference
                                                                id</th>
                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Employee
                                                                name</th>
                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Month</th>
                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Year</th>
                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Basics</th>
                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Allowances</th>

                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Edit</th>
                                                            <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Submit</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>


                                                        <s:iterator value="firsttime">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td></td>
                                                                <td class="t"><s:property value="ReferenceID" /></td>
                                                                <td class="stfnm"><s:property
                                                                        value="ffff" /></td>
                                                                <td class="mnt"><div class="form-group">

                                                                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                                                                            <s:select id="Name"
                                                                                list="#{'1':'01', '2':'02', '3':'03','4':'04','5':'05','6':'06','7':'07', '8':'08', '9':'09', '10':'10','11':'11', '12':'12'}"
                                                                                name="selctmonth" cssClass="form-control" />
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div></td>
                                                                <td class="yr">

                                                                    <h5 class="yearforpay"></h5>

                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="bb"> <input type="text" name="allowance"
                                                                        class="form-control expenses" value="" size="6" />
                                                                </td>

                                                                <td class="netsalary"><input
                                                                    class="form-control expenses_sum" size="6"></td>
                                                                <td class="wday"><s:property value="TableID" /></td>
                                                                <td>Unpaid</td>
                                                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary use-address2" data-id="9" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td><button type="button"
                                                                        class="btn btn-info use-address1">Submit</button></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </s:iterator>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <br>





                                    <!-- Modal 2 -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                                            Modal content
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                        id="closeMark">&times;</button>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">



    <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Reference</label>
                                                            <div class="col-xs-5 ">

                                                                    <input type='text' name="examDate1" class="form-control"
                                                                        id="Referenceid" /> 

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>


                                                        <div align="center">
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary updatemodul"
                                                                >Update</button>
                                                        </div>


                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                        data-dismiss="modal" id="modalReset">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->




                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Script

```
 $(".updatemodul").click(function() {

                var vlue= $('#Referenceid').val();
                var $tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text() == vlue;
                }).closest("tr");

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'submitonebyonestaff',
                    dataType : 'JSON',
                    data : {
                         allownce : $row.find(".allw").find("input").val(),         
                        Refid : $row.find(".t").text(),

                    },

                    success : function(data, success) {

                      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                      var text6 = $tableRow.find(".allw").find("input").val(); 


                      alert("sucess")

                    },
                    error : function(data, error) {
                        alert("error")

                    }

                });

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Why is the model itself inside `tbody`? How are you loading the rows in the table? and what script have you tried so far? We need a bit more details `:)`

Comment: Thank u for response i got td value through iterator and i have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want like this?. check this fiddle.
[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/fe1qxpq4/3/)

I have added this script and some class in html.

```
$(document).on("click", ".editbuttton", function() {
        var RecordId = $(this).closest("tr").find(".ReferenceID").text();
        $("#myModal #Referenceid").val(RecordId);


    });

    $(".updatemodul").click(function() {

        var vlue = $('#Referenceid').val();
        var $tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == vlue;
        }).closest("tr");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'submitonebyonestaff',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                allownce: $row.find(".allw").find("input").val(),
                Refid: $row.find(".t").text(),

            },

            success: function(data, success) {

                var ReferenceID = data.id;
                var UpdateHtml = "<td>" + ReferenceID + "</td>you all td here";
                $("#dataTS").find("#ReferenceID_" + ReferenceID).empty().append(UpdateHtml);
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                var text6 = $tableRow.find(".allw").find("input").val();



                alert("sucess")

            },
            error: function(data, error) {
                alert("error")

            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: Thank u for response yes it is correct but the thing is if I change value 0f 2 to 3 then  Reference value should be 3 in td

Comment: then you want to call `$.ajax({` onchange event

Comment: (".updatemodul").click(function() { yes , i tried it but the problem i am not getting how to place value of changed referencrid of particular row

Comment: just add id to `<tr id="ReferenceID_2">` you will get refrenece id in ajax response. you can replace the value by this `<tr id="ReferenceID_2">`

Comment: thank u i ll try this but I have doubt does only particular row will update

Comment: I didnt get you. you should append the id dynamically `<tr id="ReferenceID_2">`

Comment: first, i will try this and will tell u my doubts and thank u

Comment: hi.. i try it but i dint get

Comment: for reference 1 textbox value allowance value in modal as to place in td "s allowance and thanks for ur time